# value not showing on view, but able to print on console and coming in controller, angularJs & ionic

Tags: angularjs, controller, ionic-framework

```
 (function() {
 'use strict';
 angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('mrSearchCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {


$scope.keyword = null;
var userToken =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));
  $scope.SearchMrHistory = function(){

   var searchData = {
     'keyword': $scope.keyword
   };

   $http.post("url?requestToken=" + userToken.token + "&start=0&end=5", searchData)
   .success(function(searchData, status)  {
    //  alert("searched");
    for(var i=0; i < searchData.length; i++)

      $scope.patientName = searchData[i].patientName;
       console.log("Patient Name" + $scope.patientName);
```

Able to see this patientName in console but not in view and my view is like:

```
<div class="list" ng-controller="mrSearchCtrl">
  <div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <input placeholder="Search MR" id="SearchMrDetail" type="text" ng-model="keyword">

    </label>
    <button class="button" ng-click="SearchMrHistory()">Search</button>
          </div>
</div>
 <ion-list>
  <span ng-show="patientName">  Searched Name : {{patientName}}  </span>
```

NOTHING is coming on view, its empty, Please help out.

Comment: The code you gave us isn't valid at all, so please give us the complete code and we will try to help you.

Comment: only two files im using here, that i have pasted also, route is remaining and that isn't a problem. what more you want to understand ?